# Let h : C → C be an analytic function such that h(0) = 0; h(1\2) = 5, and |h(z)| < 10 for |z| < 1.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, analyticity

Let h : C → C be an analytic function such that h(0) = 0; h(1\2) = 5, and |h(z)| < 10 for
|z| < 1. Then,

(a) the set {z : |h(z)| = 5} is unbounded by the Maximum Principle;

(b) the set {z : |h'(z)| = 5} is a circle of strictly positive radius;

(c) h(1) = 10;

(d) regardless of what h' is, h'' ≡ 0.

A note to the reader: Actually I am preparing for an exam which is due next month. I know very little complex analysis and so I am trying to study only the key concepts. What I mean to say is I want to focus on topics/formulaes/concepts which might help me solve the above problem. So I would request you to mention the topics required in order to solve these questions.

My attempt: I know the cauchy riemann equations but using them here leads to complicated equations containing partial derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Apply [Schwarz lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma) to $f(z)/10$.

Comment: By Schwarz lemma, we conclude $\vert h(z) \vert \leq 10 \vert z \vert$ for  $\vert z \vert <1$. From this how to conclude the last two?

Comment: @ChinnapparajR There is a complete answer in the [linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2783213/a-possible-application-of-schwarz-lemma?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Ok! the answer in the linked question says $h(z)=10z$ on an open unit disc, not on all $\Bbb C$.  So how we conclude $h(1)=0$ and $h'' \equiv 0$ ? Can you explain it a bit more ?

Comment: @ChinnapparajR By [identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem), $h(z)=10z$ for any $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Oh! super! Thanks for the reply!