# A possible application of Schwarz lemma

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, analytic-functions

[Here][1]

[1]: [Let h : C → C be an analytic function such that h(0) = 0; h(1\2) = 5, and |h(z)| < 10 for |z| < 1.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1227130/let-h-c-%E2%86%92-c-be-an-analytic-function-such-that-h0-0-h1-2-5-and-hz?s=1%7C107.7809) The first two options can be eliminated using the function $h(z)=10z$. Third option is true by Maximum Modulus Principle because it says the maximum is obtained only on the boundary. However, I could not prove the last one. Is Schwarz lemma useful here? If yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply Schwarz Lemma to $\frac {f(z)} {10}$. We get $|f(z)| \leq 10|z|$ and, since equality holds for $z=\frac  1 2$, we must have $f(z)=10z$ (by the second half of Schwarz Lemma). Hence c) and d) are true.

Comment: But second half of Schwarz lemma says, if equality hold for some non zero point in $D$, then $f$ has the form $$f(z)=\alpha z$$ where $\vert \alpha \vert=1$.  But how $f(z)=10z $ here ? because $\vert 10 \vert \neq 1$. can you explain sir?

Comment: I understand the answer now! Since by Second half of schwarz lemma. $$\frac{f(z)}{10}=cz$$ where $\vert c \vert =1$. But given initial conditions implies $c=1$, so $f(z)=10z$. I also understand why you does't respond to me for the previous comment, because you are saying "Spoon feeding is for babies, not for college students !"

Comment: @ChinnapparajR This is an old post and I cannot say now why I didn't respond to your query. I generally respond to all queries on my answers. Sorry for not responding.

Comment: Fine! no problem sir!